# Scale and crop image

Tags: php, image, symfony, ezpublish, ezplatform

I'm trying to scale image and to crop it to certain size from center.

Basically if I want image to be 240x160 (scale 1.5:1) and I have Image that is 900x800 (scale 1.125:1) and use these settings:

```
filters:
    - { name: geometry/scaledownonly, params: [240, 160] }
    - { name: geometry/crop, params: [240, 160, 0, 0] }
```

But I cant get desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your site `image_variations` block of your site settings yaml, try adding the following:

```
image_variation_name:
    reference: ~
    filters:
        - { name: geometry/scaledownonly, params: [240, 160] }
        - { name: thumbnail, params: { size: [240, 160], mode: outbound } }
```

The above block will do two things. First, your image will scaled down to the appropriate size (you already had that bit). Next, the thumbnail filter will crop the image from the middle out (center crop) to the desired dimentions.

Comment: eZ Publish provided filters can be found here: https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Images.

However, eZ also lets you use the filters provided by the LiipImagineBundle, those docs can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters.html.

Comment: I knew about the official eZ filters, but did not know I could use `Liip`'s filters. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the result you chase after would fit to the following configuration:

```
...
image_variations:
    your_alias_name:
        reference: ~
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [240, 160], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
...
```

This setting will yield a scaled down version cropped to the center (to you're desired size).
That is assuming you are using the implemented image-alias-system of ezplatform though.

Hope thats the answer you are looking for :)